# adding material design collection to Android Studio's Asset Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-assets, android-icons

Is there a way to add the [Material Design Collection](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html) to Android Studio's **Asset Studio**: so that when I "right click on `drawable`>`New`>`Image Asset`" I can pick them from there.

I am using `Android Studio 1.3.2`. So when I tried to follow [How to import set of icons into Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700593/how-to-import-set-of-icons-into-android-studio-project?lq=1) the closest I got was

File > Other Settings > Default Settings >

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the plugin "Android Drawable Import" (*)
2. Restart Android Studio
3. "New" -> "Icon Pack Drawable Importer"

   - = Settings -> Plugings -> Search

Had the same Problem and thought the plugin would be installed by default in AS 1.3.x