# Android Developer Vs Android Designing

Tags: android, android-gui

This is the question of its own kind may be some one has come across same condition which I have to face many times when it comes on UI and graphics.

And insist to forget about different screen sizes and resolution and just focus on the dps.  Where as all the designers focus on the Resolutions and pixels.

So if I have to make the background screen for the splash activity so then What I am supposed to tell him If I want him to design for all folders I mean 
mdpi, hpi, xhdpi , xxhdpi , xxxhdpi.

So first question is what size should I tell them to draw and for mdpi and hdpi and xhdpi and xxhdpi and xxxhdpi ? what should I tell them ?

Android designing is I think really very tough if you want to support different devices of different densities.

what would you suggest to make the the Graphics for all devices and what resolution should be the starting point ?

Answer (score 1):

In the particular case of images that are meant to be backgrounds, it's okay to have a reasonably large image (1280x1920) and stick it in the drawable-nodpi folder.

Otherwise, for icons, your designer needs to [learn about dp sizes](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp-). Then ideally they'll create a nice big high-res icon (say 512x512px), and either you or they will scale it to the appropriate sizes using something like [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example)

Comment: so you mean for splash activity background and all screen background should be scaled to 1280*1920 and android will take care of it ?

Comment: Yeah, but never scale them up! If your original is only 600x600 you might as well just use that. (plus make sure they go in the nodpi folder)

Answer (score 0):

Tell your designer to make high resolution image,that means xxxhdpi or xxhdpi as per your requirement. so that we can converting it to lower resolution.

If you are using android studio then you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704026/3758898) plugin.
by this you have to use `Scaled Drawable import`

Comment: Android Studio 1.3.2 include it's own scaling tools when importing, you don't have to install a new one.

Comment: @kishan  how I am supposed to tell the resolution ot XXXhdpi ?  designer as tell me the screen size so what should I tell him

Comment: It is recommended to not provide images (other than launcher icon) for xxxhdpi density, since android can effectively upscale images from xhdpi density folder at runtime. It will minimize your app's size. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html