# Can't access drawable resource from menu for navigation drawer

Tags: android

Am trying to add icons to a navigation drawer but somehow, I can't access resources in the `res/drawable` folder.

This is the list of icons I have in my `drawable-hdpi` folder:

[image]

But I can't access any of them using the correct method:

[image]

It says `cannot resolve the symbol '@drawable/ic_action_user'`

This is strange because I have another application open that uses the exact same method and it works fine there.I've tried invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio with no luck.

All I get are the icons in the `drawable-v21` folder:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems to be already answered.Please check this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28704026/2772552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created **drawable-hdpi** folder inside **drawable**.
You should move it to **res** folder
.

Comment: Silly me.Didn't notice that

Answer (score 1):

Try to use gradle task 'clean' and rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

You need to put images in `drawable` folder instead of `drawable-v21`. Create below `drawable` folder under `res` .

> drawable-ldpi
>
> drawable-mdpi
>
> drawable-hdpi
>
> drawable-xhdpi
>
> drawable-xxhdpi

Then **Clean & Rebuild** your Project . Hope this helps .

You can check #SO
**[How to import set of icons into Android Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700593/how-to-import-set-of-icons-into-android-studio-project/28704026#28704026)**

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Good to hear .Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

First check that the icons is available in your resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your images in the main drawable directory (res/drawable).. Not in the sub one (res/drawable-hdpi)

Comment: No need to keep in "main drawable"  you can access  from  sub one

Answer (score 0):

you might have set min sdk version to 21 in gradle, set it to below version or copy all drawables in `drawables-hdpi` to `drawables-v21`, as only drawables in `drawables-v21` will be used in versions equal to and above 21